# comparing enum with multiple values and no bitwise

Tags: objective-c, c, enums, comparison

How can I compare a enum to a variable if the enum contains mulitple possible values?

Ex: for the following enum

```
typedef enum {
    EnumValueA = 2,
    EnumValueB = 3,
    EnumValueC = 4,
    EnumValueD = (0 | -1)
} EnumValues;
```

When comparing a variable like `BOOL result = (a == EnumValueD)` I get `NO` if `int a = 0` and `YES` if `int a = -1`.

Also, this enum is inside a component so I just can't change it..How

How can I make this comparison return YES for both `0` and `-1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is based on a misunderstanding. The line

```
EnumValueD = (0 | -1)
```

does *not* indicate "multiple values". That is a "bitwise-or" operator: it performs an operation (bitwise) on the numbers zero and minus one, and yields just *one* answer. It's a curious bit of code (probably having to do with integer byte size issues), but you only need to test against -1. (If you really want to be safe you could test against `(0|-1)`, I suppose.)

Moral: Don't confuse logical-or `||` with the bitwise-or operator `|`.

Comment: What a silly mistake of mine... Tks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Make it be like this:

```
typedef enum {
    EnumValueA = 1,
    EnumValueB = 2,
    EnumValueC = 4,
    EnumValueD = 8
} EnumValues;
```

So you can use the logic or to combine a value so that can have multiple values.
Then check if contains a single value using the logic and.
So for example:

```
EnumValues val= EnumValueD | EnumValueC;
```

Then to read values:

```
if(value & EnumValueA)
    actionA();
if(value & EnumValueB)
    actionB();
if(value & enumValueC)
    actionC();
if(value & enumValueD)
    actionD();
```

So if has multiple values, multiple actions will be executed.
If you want you can also put a value which includes multiple values, instead of using an or:

```
typedef enum {
    EnumValueA = 1,
    EnumValueB = 2,
    EnumValueC = 4,
    EnumValueD = 8,
    EnumValueCAndD= 12
} EnumValues;
```

Comment: Tks for the attention but I don't think you read the question entirely, 1st where I wrote `this enum is inside a component so I just can't change it` and specially the title, where it says `no bitwise`